# CORS policy problem in react js client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, webapi

I created a Formik login form and call to react js fetch method. Add cors in web api end and successfully run in Postman and jquery. How to call "token_type": "bearer", through react js? cors is also enabled in web api and also generate Token successfully. How to call  this url  `https://localhost:44323/token` through react js?

My code is

```
 onSubmit={(values) => {
                fetch('https://localhost:44323/token', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    header: { 'Content-type': 'application/json,multipart/form-data' },                    
                    data: JSON.stringify(values)
                })
                    .then(r => r.json())
                    .then(res => {
                        console.log(res)
                    });
            }}>
```

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08QT7.png)

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the problem can be found in the following error message shown:

***"Access to fetch at https://localhost:44323/token from origin http://localhost:3000 has been blocked by CORS policy. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource ...."***

---

**How to fix the problem?**

The problem can be fixed in these ways:

**1. Allow the origin (http://localhost:3000) on the server (Recommended)**

This can be done by adding the following header to HTTP response on the server side:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
```

**2. Send Fetch request in the 'no-cors' mode**

This can be done by updating the fetch request as follows:

```
fetch( 'https://localhost:44323/token', 
       { 
           method: 'POST',
           mode: 'no-cors',
           headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
           body: JSON.stringify(data)
       }
)
.then(response => {
        // Code for processing the response
      }
)
.catch((error) => {
        // Code for handling the error
      }
)
```

**More information:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch